# How to add custom Haml helper to Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, helper

I've created Haml helper and put it as file in path app/helpers/haml_helper.rb

```
module Haml::Helpers
  def build_segment(files)
    files.each do |f|
      if f[:dir] == nil
        haml_tag :li do
          haml_tag :a, :class=>"file", :href=>f[:name] do
            f[:name]
          end
        end
      else
        haml_tag :li do
          haml_tag :a, :class=>"folder", :href=>f[:name] do
            f[:name]
          end
        end
        haml_tag :ul do
          build_segment(f[:dir])
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But then I've got an error:

```
LoadError in SourceFilesController#index
Expected /home/megas/Work/read_the_code/app/helpers/haml_helper.rb 
to define HamlHelper
```

SourceFilesController#index is an action which going to use this custom helper.

How to add custom haml helper to the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when you have haml_helper.rb, it expects it to define HamlHelper .... but you wanted Haml::Helper. So:

```
/helpers/haml/helpers
```

This is the same when you have namespaced controllers. Admin::CustomersController is at app/controllers/admin/customers_controller.rb

Comment: In some article I read that I should put haml helpers in Haml::Helper module. Actually it just should be in controller's helper.